# Counting the inputs in a <p> using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a

```
      <p style="display: block;" class="title fieldChoices">Choices:
          <input value="option1" maxlength="150" id="Choice1"/>
          <input value="option2" maxlength="150" id="Choice2"/>
      </p>
```

I am trying to count how many input boxes there are in this `fieldChoices` using
JQUery.  Please suggest a way how to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("p.fieldChoices input").length;
```

Comment: will this work since the class op the p is "title fieldChoices"?

Comment: That's actually two classes: title and fieldChoices. So yes this will work. The space separator delimits multiple classes.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("p input").length;
```